# Design feedback control law to make the whole matrix Hurwitz

Tags: matrices, control-theory, block-matrices, linear-control, hurwitz-matrices

Suppose $(A_1, B_1)$ and $(A_2, B_2)$ are both stabilizable. Then we know that we can find some $K_1$ and $K_2$ to make $A_1+B_1K_1$ and $A_2+B_2K_2$ Hurwitz, respectively. Now, for non-zero constant matrices $C_1$ and $C_2$ with proper dimensions, can we always design $K_1$ and $K_2$ to make the following matrix Hurwitz? If so, how to prove it? Thanks in advance!

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {A_1  + B_1 K_1 } & {C_1 }  \\
   {C_2 } & {A_2  + B_2 K_2 }  \\
\end{array}} \right]
$$

Comment: I'm not totally sure but it seems that sufficient conditions would be:
1. $C_2 B_1 = C_1 B_2 = 0$
2. $A_1 C_2 = C_2 A_1$ and $A_2 C_1 = C_1 A_2$
But surely this is a hard problem.

Comment: Also note that these conditions implies that null space of $C_2$ should be equal to controllable subspace of $(A_1, B_1)$.